# Consulta sobre MYSQL, necesito bloquear a usuarios en un menú

Tags: php, mysql

por acá nuevamente con dudas de PHP y MYSQL, estoy desarrollando un menú para un sistema de capacitaciones, en el cual se irán mostrando items de acuerdo al tipo de usuario (su "estamento"), y actualmente tengo esta query:

```
$sql1="SELECT 
usuarios.estamento 
FROM usuarios 
where usuarios.id = '$user_id'
and usuarios.estamento='001' 
";
```

El valor de esa query lo guardo en la variable $sql1, y dependiendo del resultado, hago un array con los elementos del menu que el usuario puede ver dependiendo de que si su estamento es 001 (jefe) o no,

```
 if($result=mysqli_query($con, $sql1))
{
while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){  
echo"
<li class='has-dropdown'>
<a href='cursos/creacion_curso.php'>Creación de cursos</a>
</li>"; 

echo"
<li class='has-dropdown'>
<a href='#'>Modificación de cursos</a>
</li>
";   

echo"
<li class='has-dropdown'>
<a href='cursos/aprobacion.php'>Aprobación de inscritos</a>
</li>
"; 

echo"
<li class='has-dropdown'>
<a href='cursos/asistencia_alumnos.php'>Validar Asistencia</a>
</li>
";  

echo"
<li class='has-dropdown'>
<a href='cursos/informes.php'>Informes</a>
</li>"; 
}
}  ?>
```

El problema esta en que, algunos de esos items, los necesito mostrar según el estamento del usuario (por ejemplo, si el estamento del usuario es 002, el podrá ver el ítem "informes"), y había hecho este cambio en la query,

```
SELECT 
usuarios.estamento 
FROM usuarios 
where usuarios.id = '$user_id'
and usuarios.estamento='001'││ usuarios.estamento='002'
```

Pero no me realiza bien la discriminación e, independiente del estamento del usuario, me muestra todos los items del menú,

¿Que puedo hacer en este caso?, ¿Como modifico la consulta?,

Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El `pipe (|)` en `mysql` no es parte canónica del lenguaje, en su lugar utiliza `OR`

El problema está que debes encerrar los estamentos en un pequeño scope, eso retornará un set de usuarios que posteriormente serán evaluados con el `AND`

Esto debería funcionar

```
SELECT 
usuarios.estamento 
FROM usuarios 
where usuarios.id = '$user_id'
and ( usuarios.estamento='001' or usuarios.estamento='002' )
```

Comment: Sencillo y útil, muchísimas gracias :)

Comment: Recuerda marcar como correcta si te funcionó. Saludos